# Extract text from attachments in .MSG files stored on a drive

Tags: python, python-3.x, msg, eml

I have used mailparser module in python3 to extract attachments in .EML files (code shown below)

```
import mailparser
mail = mailparser.parse_from_file(filepath)
msg_body = mail.body.split('--- mail_boundary ---', 1)[0]
msg_subject = mail.subject
msg_attachments = mail.attachments
print(msg_subject)
```

I am not able to use the above code for .MSG files. It does not work. Is there a better way of doing this ?
I have tried extract_msg, email_parser but no luck.

Comment: indentation is a problem here? what you mean it doesn't work? what error does it give?

Comment: Oops, edited the question. No issue with indentation. The program does not print anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `mail-parser` package listed one pypi, then according to their [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/mail-parser/), you have to install `libemail-outlook-message-perl` package along with the `mail-parser` package.

On Debian:

```
apt-get install libemail-outlook-message-perl
```

For details, you can do (assuming you have a debian os):

```
apt-cache show libemail-outlook-message-perl
```

You can find the downloads for other packages [here](https://pkgs.org/download/libemail-outlook-message-perl).

[This](https://github.com/mvz/email-outlook-message-perl) is their github repository.

If you have windows then a quick solution will be to convert .msg files into .eml files, using websites like [this](https://www.jitbit.com/msg2eml/). Another will be to manually build the package from their github repository.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Ruturaj I am running python on windows. And libemail-outlook-message-perl has packages for debian and unix only

Comment: In this case, a quick solution will be - convert your .msg files into .eml files, also have you checked their github repository?

Comment: can I install this on windows as well?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to do it.
In my work, I test the MSG PY module.
This is Microsoft Outlook .msg file module for Python. 
The module allows you to easy create/read/parse/convert Outlook .msg files. 
The module does not require Microsoft Outlook to be installed on the machine or any other third party application or library in order to work.
For example:

```
from independentsoft.msg import Message

appointment = Message("e:\\appointment.msg")

print("subject: " + str(appointment.subject))
print("start_time: " + str(appointment.appointment_start_time))
print("end_time: " + str(appointment.appointment_end_time))
print("location: " + str(appointment.location))
print("is_reminder_set: " + str(appointment.is_reminder_set))
print("sender_name: " + str(appointment.sender_name))
print("sender_email_address: " + str(appointment.sender_email_address))
print("display_to: " + str(appointment.display_to))
print("display_cc: " + str(appointment.display_cc))
print("body: " + str(appointment.body))
```